# NonUniqueResultException in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

In a Spring Boot / Kotlin application I have this repository:

```
interface CatRepository : CrudRepository<Cat, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT c.color FROM cat c", nativeQuery = true)
    fun findColors(): List<String>
}
```

Then in my controller I have this:

```
@Controller
class HtmlController(private val repository: CatRepository) {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index(model: Model): String {
        model["colors"] = repository.findColors()
        return "index"
    }

}
```

Then in my template I have this:

```
<select name="color">
    {{#colors}}
        <option value="">{{.}}</option>
    {{/colors}}
</select>
```

When there is only one `cat` in the database's `cat` table, this works. When I add another, I get this error:

> NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you set logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug and post the generated SQL statements?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes. It logs the exact query I have in the annotation.

Comment: It's just a guess but can you name your method findAllColors()

Comment: A very good guess! If you write an answer I'll mark it right (extra points for saying why...)

Comment: Done. Thanks for accepting my answer. I'm happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your method

```
findAllColors()
```

to tell Spring Data that the return type is collection.

I cannot find any documentation but there is a blog post about this topic that says:

> 1. Be able to find methods by name and (raw) parameter types.
> 2. Methods named …All(…) affect a collection of items and/or return a collection.
> 3. Methods taking an identifier are named …ById(…). 4 Let’s drop the ID extends Serializable requirement.

Source: https://spring.io/blog/2017/06/20/a-preview-on-spring-data-kay#improved-naming-for-crud-repository-methods